# error api, no se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de identidad de la tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

me preguntaba si me ayudan a solucionar este problema pasa que cuando intento meter datos en una tabla productos me dice que la columna del campo identity no puede contener un valor explicito, pasa que yo no le meto nada ya que queda en 0 y por eso me marca eso, pero en otros tablas pasa  lo mismo pero si funciona.

esta es mi tabla de sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esta es mi modelo de la api producto el que uso para llenar

```
public class Producto
{
    [Display(Name = "Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(150, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Debe dar una Descripcion")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre es Obligatorio")]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Año en que se Ingreso al Inventario")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Digitar el Año en que se Ingreso")]
    [Range(1900, 2022, ErrorMessage = "El Año Debe Estar Entre (1900-2022)")]
    public int Año { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Precio de Compra")]
    [Range(0, 1000000)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Digitar un Precio")]
    public int precio { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Precio de Venta")]
    [Range(0, 1000000)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Digitar un Precio")]
    public int precioVenta { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Utilidad (%)")]
    [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "La Utilidad debe ser mayor a 0")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe Digitar Una Utilidad")]
    public int Utilidad { get; set; }

    public int idprovedor { get; set; }

    public virtual Provedor provedor { get; set; }

}
```

aqui es donde capturo el objeto y lo guardo en la base de datos

```
    public async Task<Producto> guardarProducto(Producto nuevoProducto)
    {
        _context.Productos.Add(nuevoProducto);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return nuevoProducto;

    }
```

este es el error que me sale

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que no entiendo es que me marca error con el provedor, pero tecnicamente si mi tabla guarda una llave foranea en producto de un provedor, pues yo debo ingresar el id del provedor pero nose porque me marca ese error.

asi es como lo estoy probando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradezco su ayuda, nose en que tengo el problema el error marca la llave primaria , pero si en productos ya debo desplegar los id disponibles de provedores, técnicamente debo seleccionar uno, pero nose porque al meterlo me marca que no puedo meter valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una propiedad que se llame Id en entity framework es automaticamente PK y auto incrementable. Y esto último es lo que creo te causa problemas.

En Proveedor estas ingresando una Id, aquí veo 2 posibilidades:

**1) Quieres crear un Proveedor con una Id en particular, entonces debes sacar el auto increment de esta manera  en el DbContext**

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //Debes agregar esta linea
    modelBuilder.Entity<Provedor>().Property(b => b.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

    OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
}
```

**2) Estas creando un nuevo producto, pero el proveedor ya existe.**

Entonces no es necesario que envíes el objeto proveedor dentro del producto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: me suena más esta 2) Estas creando un nuevo producto, pero el proveedor ya existe. , pero entonces no entiendo si yo ingreso 3 provedores, y luego agrego un producto que está asociado a un proveedor, como los almaceno ? técnicamente debía poder meter en la llave foránea del producto el id del proveedor ?

Comment: por eso en mi tabla producto vez la llave foranea de id de provedor , entonces cuando seleccione un id de provedor en producto como lo guardo ?

Comment: solo deberia enviar el id del provedor entonces?

Comment: @LiulinContreras Claro, solo envías idprovedor, ahí está el FK  (Creo que el nombre está al revés debería llamarse ProvedorId)

Comment: @LiulinContreras Imagina que provedor tuviera 1000 campos, sería una burrada que el sistema te pidiera que cada vez que ingresas un producto, tuvieras que además ingresar los 1000 campos de proveedor que ya existen en la BD. La manera en que lo estás haciendo, es para INSERTAR un objeto padre y su objeto hijo AMBOS de un golpe, pero veo que no es tu caso

Comment: si creo que tienes razon no estaba haciendolo bien porque si los registros de la tabla hijo ya los tengo en productos solo debo pues ingresar productos y asociar el id del hijo que es provedor

Comment: muchas gracias que tengas buen dia

Comment: @LiulinContreras Solucionaste el problema?

Comment: si si pude el problema era que yo pues como ves metia la llave foranea y luego metia los datos del provedor, cuando el provedor ya existia, entonces como el id del provedor de su tabla era primaria, alli era donde me marcaba que no podia insertar un dato explicito jejee

Comment: así perdón, gracias por comentar mas bien, buenas noches